# Globbing and find command. Difference between encapsulating globbing in " " and not

Tags: command-line, find, wildcards

Why does `find . -name "*.jav"` work while `find . -name *.jav` does not work if there are more than 1 `.jav` files? What do the `" "` do and why is the `"*.jav"` not interpreted as a literal string?

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards are expanded by the shell, not by the command. `find` is one of the few commands that performs wildcard matching that's similar to the shell, in its own time.

When you run `ls *.jav`, first the shell expands `*.jav` to the list of matching files, e.g. `file1.jav` `file2.jav` `file3.jav`, and then the shell calls `ls` with the resulting list of arguments `file1.jav` `file2.jav` `file3.jav`. That's why you see the same list of file names with `echo *.jav`, even though `echo` knows nothing about files and doesn't care whether its arguments are file names.

When you run `find . -name "*.jav"`:

1. The shell parses the command line to recognize special characters and split it into words and puntuation. Here there's just a list of words `find`, `.`, `-name`, `*.jav` where the `*` is quoted. Since `*` is quoted, it's an ordinary character as far as the shell is concerned.
2. The shell runs the command `find` with the specified list of arguments: `.`, `-name`, `*.jav`.
3. `find` looks for files whose name matches the pattern `*.jav` in any directory under the current directory.

When you run `find . -name *.jav` and there are no files matching `*.jav`:

1. The shell parses the command line to recognize special characters and split it into words and puntuation. Here there's just a list of words `find`, `.`, `-name`, `*.jav` where the `*` is not quoted.
2. Since the word `*.jav` contains an unquoted wildcard character, the shell performs filename generation. Since there are no matching file names, the pattern remains unexpanded.
3. The shell runs the command `find` with the resulting list of arguments, which is `.`, `-name`, `*.jav`.
4. `find` looks for files whose name matches the pattern `*.jav` in any directory under the current directory.

When you run `find . -name *.jav` and the current directory contains `file1.jav`, `file2.jav` and `file3.jav`:

1. The shell parses the command line to recognize special characters and split it into words and puntuation. Here there's just a list of words `find`, `.`, `-name`, `*.jav` where the `*` is not quoted.
2. Since the word `*.jav` contains an unquoted wildcard character, the shell performs filename generation: `*.jav` is replaced by the list of matching file names.
3. The shell runs the command `find` with the resulting list of arguments, which is `.`, `-name`, `file1.jav`, `file2.jav`, `file3.jav`.
4. `find` complains about a syntax error when it reaches `file2.jav`.

When you run `find . -name *.jav` and the current directory contains a single matching file `file.jav`:

1. The shell parses the command line to recognize special characters and split it into words and puntuation. Here there's just a list of words `find`, `.`, `-name`, `*.jav` where the `*` is not quoted.
2. Since the word `*.jav` contains an unquoted wildcard character, the shell performs filename generation: `*.jav` is replaced by the list of matching file names.
3. The shell runs the command `find` with the resulting list of arguments, which is `.`, `-name`, `file.jav`.
4. `find` sees a perfectly valid command, but it is probably not what you intended: `find` is told to look for files called `file.jav` in any directory, not to look for any file matching `*.jav`.

(Shell evaluation and expansion has a lot of other features. I only mentioned the ones that are relevant here.)

(What I describe is the default behavior of most common shells: sh, bash, dash, ksh, … Some shells can be configured to display an error instead of running a command with unexpanded wildcards, or to expand non-matching wildcards to an empty list. None of those would help here.)

Comment: You forgot to mention what OP asked for: Why does it work with exactly one matching filename - but I think this can easily be derived from your answer.

Comment: @rexkogitans Good point, added. This case wasn't explicitly mentioned in the question but it's an important one.

Comment: well done, especially saying "but it is probably not what you intended" in point 4.